# how to excute a Sp with dynamic parameter

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic, execute, declare

I have created a stored procedure to find name and designation by supplying income of an employee

```
Create  PROCEDURE GetEmployeessalaryInOutputVariable
(
    @Income INT,                 -- Input parameter,  Income of the Employee
    @FirstName VARCHAR (30) OUT, -- Output parameter to collect the Employee name
    @Title VARCHAR (30)OUT       -- Output Parameter to collect the Employee designation
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT FirstName=@FirstName, Title=@Title 
    FROM Salaries WHERE @Income=Income
END
```

After this I tried to execute the Sp as follows

```
Declare @FirstName as varchar(30) -- Declaring the variable to collect the Employeename
Declare @Title as varchar(30)     -- Declaring the variable to collect the Designation
Execute GetEmployeessalaryInOutputVariable 500 , @FirstName output, @Title output
select @FirstName,@Title as Designation
```

As soon as I write the above statement, it displays an error displaying

```
Invalid object name GetEmployeessalaryInOutputVariable
```

Why is it behaving like that although the procedure has been created and exists?

Also, how can I run the query to get proper results ?

Comment: CAn you please provide the formatted the Codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create  PROCEDURE GetEmployeessalaryInOutputVariable
(
    @Income INT,                 -- Input parameter,  Income of the Employee
    @FirstName VARCHAR (30) OUT, -- Output parameter to collect the Employee name
    @Title VARCHAR (30)OUT       -- Output Parameter to collect the Employee designation
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @FirstName = FirstName, @Title=Title 
    FROM Salaries WHERE @Income=Income
END
```

Your SP should be like this

Comment: Thank u The Sp u gave is correct but the problem is its displaying  only a single row while there are 6 rows with income 500 please suggest any solution

Comment: @ashu you should change your SP to insert into a table

`insert into <table_name>
SELECT  FirstName, Title 
    FROM Salaries WHERE @Income=Income
`
after the SP Execute get the data from the table....

Answer (score 1):

```
Execute GetEmployeessalaryInOutputVariable 500 , 'FirstName', 'Title'
```

OR

```
Declare @FirstName as varchar(30)
set @FirstName = 'FirstName'
Declare @Title as varchar(30)   
set @Title = 'title'
Execute GetEmployeessalaryInOutputVariable 500 , @FirstName, @Title
```